# how to align/justify text to right constantly(when writing and when not) in tkinters text widget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to make everything typed in my text widget to be automatically RTL(right to left), but I dont know how to do this. I have read many forums and threads and subsReddits and I couldn't find the answer to my question: how to change the default LTR to RTL in tkinter text widgets.
I'm using python 3.12.1 and windows.

I've tried:

```
textwidget.tag_configure("tagName", justify='right')
textwidget.insert('1.0', " ")#here
textwidget.tag_add("TagName", 1.0, "end")
```

It doesnt work forever and if some one brings the text cursor to the top of the text widget it will be deleted. If the insert has empty text it also does not work.

I've also tried:

```
from awesometkinter.bidirender import add_bidi_support
add_bidi_support(textwidget)
```

All this does is fix the text for linux and is not what I want right now. I also made this attempt, but it does not work as expected.

```
while True:
    if textwidget.get('1.0')=='\n' or textwidget.get('1.0',END)=='\n' or textwidget.get('1.0',END)=='':
        textwidget.insert(END, " ")
        textwidget.tag_add("retd", 1.0, "end")
    win.update()
```

This doesn't work if someone moves their cursor to the top using the up key.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs for `justify`: "The justify option **set on the first character of each line** determines how that line is justified: tk.LEFT (the default), tk.CENTER, or tk.RIGHT."

This means you need to keep reapplying the tag as new text is inserted. Especially if that text is on a new line. However, you don't have to apply an individual tag for each line, just make sure that the tag spans all of the lines. This way the first character of every line has the tag because all of the characters in the entire widget have the tag.

```py
import tkinter as tk

class Text(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.tag_config('right', justify='right')
        self.tag_add('right', '1.0', 'end')
        self.bind('<KeyRelease>', self.justify)
        
    def justify(self, event=None):
        self.tag_remove('right', '1.0', 'end')
        self.tag_add('right', '1.0', 'end')
    
        
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.config(**kwargs)
        
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        
        text = Text(self)
        text.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nswe')
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().mainloop()
```